# ingresar datos y que aparezcan en tabla usando pdo php

Tags: php, mysql

Soy un poco nuevo en esto de php y estoy intentando crear un buscador pero me da este error:

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null
>   given in.

ya que investigue y no puedo usar `mysqli_fetch_array` si estoy utilizando 
`pdo`. Quisiera saber cómo hacer para que mis datos aparezcan en la tabla mediante un array usando pdo.

Vi que se podía utilizar `foreach` pero los videos no decian como pasar los datos en una tabla sino solo en la pagina.
    si alguien podria ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

```
<?php

require 'DB.php';
if(isset($_POST['Buscar'])){

$Buscar = $_POST['Buscar'];

$sqls = $conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM estudiante WHERE Cedula LIKE '%$Buscar%' or Nombre like 
'%$Buscar%' or
Ap1 like '%$Buscar%'or Ap2 like '%$Buscar%' or Sexo like '%$Buscar%'");
$sqls->execute();

}
  ?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Buscador </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1> Buscador estudiantil </h1>

<form action="Buscador.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="Buscar" placeholder="Ingrese aquí..">
<input type="submit" value="Buscar">

</form>

<table align="center" border="1px">
 <thead>
<th> Cedula </th>
<th> Nombre completo</th>
<th> Primer apellido</th>
<th> Segundo apellido</th>
<th> Sexo </th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqls)) { ?>

<tr>

<td> <?= $row ['Cedula'] ?> </td>
<td> <?= $row ['Nombre'] ?> </td>
<td> <?= $row ['Ap1'] ?> </td>
<td> <?= $row ['Ap2'] ?> </td>
<td> <?= $row ['Sexo'] ?> </td>

</tr>

<?php }
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que de esta manera te funcionará, es una buena práctica usar BindValue en las consultas con PDO, ya que evitan inyección SQL en vez de poner directamente el parametro buscar dentro de la variable $sqls. Espero que te sirva.

```
<?php
require 'DB.php';

if(isset($_POST['Buscar'])){

    $Buscar = $_POST['Buscar'];

    $sqls = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
    FROM estudiante 
    WHERE Cedula LIKE :search OR 
    Nombre LIKE :search OR
    Ap1 LIKE :search OR 
    Ap2 LIKE :search OR
    Sexo LIKE :search");

    $sqls->bindValue(':search', '%'.$Buscar.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sqls->execute();

    $result = $sqls->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Buscador </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1> Buscador estudiantil </h1>

<form action="Buscador.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="Buscar" placeholder="Ingrese aquí..">
<input type="submit" value="Buscar">

</form>

<table align="center" border="1px">
 <thead>
<th> Cedula </th>
<th> Nombre completo</th>
<th> Primer apellido</th>
<th> Segundo apellido</th>
<th> Sexo </th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php 
if(isset($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $row) { 
?>

<tr>

<td> <?= $row ['Cedula'] ?> </td>
<td> <?= $row ['Nombre'] ?> </td>
<td> <?= $row ['Ap1'] ?> </td>
<td> <?= $row ['Ap2'] ?> </td>
<td> <?= $row ['Sexo'] ?> </td>

</tr>

<?php 
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okey intentaré esta opción

Comment: ahora me da este error al usar el foreach

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: Ah claro, por que cuando se muestra por primera vez, no hay ninguna busquéda, la variable $result no existe por que está dentro del if, voy a actualizar la respuesta

Comment: esta bien es que aun no manejo muy bien las funciones con pdo trabajaba con las de mysqli jaja

Comment: haha a vale ;-]

Comment: ahora todo bien cuando cargo en el navegador pero cuando realizo la búsqueda me tira este error con el style del pdo : Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Comment: ya vi que es que tonto jajaja

Comment: habia cambiado el marcador que tu le pusiste de search a Buscar en español y se me olvido cambiarlo en el bindvalue jajaja pero ya me sirvio muchas gracias jonas!!!

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tienes aqui:

```
$sqls->execute();
```

estas ejecutando la conexion con la consulta preparada, pero no estas guardando los datos. De esta manera no puedes iterar por elementos, porque no los tienes. Deberias hacer algo como:

```
$result = $sqls->fetchAll();
```

Con esto, almacenas en $resultado la ejecucion de la consulta (en este caso, un array con cada registro de tu select). Luego en el bucle, puedes cambiar:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqls)) { ?
```

por

```
foreach($result as $key => $record) ?
```

De esta manera estarás iterando por cada elemento de resultado. cada elemento $record representa una tupla de tu consulta resultado. Puedes acceder a cada campo con $record['campo1']...

Comment: hola gracias por responder.

Comment: pero no se supone que si uso pdo no puede usar el mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: estaba viendo y creo que debo cambiarlo por $sqls->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: Perdon. Entendi mal la pregunta. Ahora te edito la respuesta

Comment: OJO con `fetchAll()`, este método se recomienda en casos muy concretos (por ejemplo si esperas pocos datos). Si esperas muchos datos y usas `fetchAll` la memoria puede verse desbordada, por eso generalmente se usa `fetch()`, leyendo los datos dentro de un bucle, `while` generalmente. Otra cosa muy importante es indicar siempre el *fecth style*: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` u otro, de lo contrario te estaría trayendo dos veces los datos: como array asociativo y numérico, a no ser que en la configuración de la conexión hayas indicado un *fetch style*  por defecto.

Comment: y ahora me da error en el foreach: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in